# Calculate Acres in Territory using ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online

I have a map of counties with each county have assigned a corn acre attribute number. I also have a territory layer that covers multiple counties. I am curious if there is a way to calculate the amount of acres to the territory based on summing the area the territory covers in ArcGis Online.

For Example: County A has 10,000 acres but territory covers 50% of the area of the county then the territory only sums 5,000 acres?

[image]

Comment: Please decide which of ArcGIS Online and ArcGIS Pro you wish to ask about in this particular question. As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question

Comment: Hi PolyGeo I updated this after it was closed and it was not reopened. I went and created another question and it was marked as duplicate to this question. How should I move forward?

Comment: It's in the reopen queue. It has 4 votes to reopen, I think 5 are needed, so it should back open soon.

Comment: Have a look at this similar question while you wait. It's in QGIS but a similar approach should be possible in ArcGIS. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214893/calculating-proportional-area-of-polygon-within-another-layers-polygon-using-qg#214933