# Calculating total area of polygons by attribute, cut by another polygon

Tags: qgis, area

I am using QGIS 3.16. I have [Natural Englands Priority Habitat](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/4b6ddab7-6c0f-4407-946e-d6499f19fcde/priority-habitat-inventory-england) loaded, I want to produce stats for five polygons I have in a seperate shp file of area of each habitat type in each polygon to produce a table like the below.

[image]

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: Check the ["Join attributes by location (summary)"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location-summary) with Batch processing

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Thank you all, I will be a lot more descriptive next time.

Answer (score 0):

Used solution, [outlined here, to a similar problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214893/calculating-proportional-area-of-polygon-within-another-layers-polygon-using-qg?rq=1). Using Vector > geoprocessing tools > union. Then used [Group Stats plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GroupStats/) to produce the table.